# Is there any integration for Hashicorp Vault for Google Chrome?

Tags: password-manager

I want to use Hashicorp's Vault for personal passwords. Is there any method of integrating it with Google Chrome, such as a Chrome Extension? I see there is a [browser extension for Gopass](https://github.com/gopasspw/gopassbridge) and one for [Pass](https://github.com/browserpass/browserpass-extension), but I can't find one that supports that much larger Hashicorp Vault directly.